# How to create form modal to the console window

Tags: delphi, console-application, delphi-xe2

Inside console app - `GetOpenFileName()` with `Handle := FindWindow(Nil, Pchar(ConsoleTitle))` show OpenFile dialog modal to console window. Is it possible to create and show **my own form** modal to console window?

Comment: Why would you make a console app open up a dialog box?

Comment: @WarrenP - I have old cobol console app. I must add some functionality (execl files import with column selection, ...) for which I have ready to use GUI solution. And for me this GUI applet is acceptable only if it is modal to the console window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the console window the window owner of your form and disable it when showing your form. Something like the following:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  windows,
  forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

const
  ConsoleClass = 'ConsoleWindowClass';

var
  console: HWND;
  len: DWORD;
  title: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of Char;

begin
  try
    len := GetConsoleTitle(title, SizeOf(title));
    Win32Check(Bool(len));
    console := FindWindow(ConsoleClass, title);
    Win32Check(Bool(console));
    Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
    try
      EnableWindow(console, False);
      try
        Form1.HandleNeeded;
        SetWindowLongPtr(Form1.Handle, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, console);
        Form1.ShowModal;
      finally
        EnableWindow(console, True);
      end;
    finally
      Form1.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you! Form1.HandleNeeded; and SetWindowLong(Form1.Handle, GWL_HWNDPARENT, console); is what I needed :)

Comment: This code seems to explicitly perform certain tasks that would have been done anyway. Doesn't reading the `Handle` property already call `HandleNeeded`? And won't `ShowModal` disable the parent console window?

Comment: @Rob - (1) Apparently yes. (2) No, the console window is not enumerated with `EnumThreadWindows` which `DisableTaskWindows` calls.